# React-admin. How to show on separate page user activity

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

**What I have.**

I have few resources in my project -> `users` and `user_activity`.
Edpoint for getting user_activity looks like this:

`curl base_url/rpc/user_activity?id=user_id -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET`

Some React admin code

```
<Resource
   name="user"
   options={{ label: 'Users' }}
   list={ UsersList }
   create={ UsersCreate}
   edit={ UsersEdit }
   show={ UsersShow }
/>
<Resource name="user_activity"/>
```

**What I need.**

On the edit and show User page to put the button - "Activity", onclick on which I need to go to another page and show there table of User's Activity according to user_id.
I was thinking that for showing data from user_activity reasource I can use  or new useQuery hook, but it should get somehow user_id as an argument, then how to pass it? Also was cheking  as I understood it shows the data connected by the key from different resource but it show it at the same component and I need it to be on separate page.

**How to do it?**

What do you think is the best way to create a page and with what component inside in order to show the user_activity by user_id from another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a "ReferenceManyField" ?

I do something very similair using tabs instead of a new page.
For example:

```
<TabbedShowLayout>
            <Tab label="activity" path="activity">
                <ReferenceManyField
                    addLabel={false}
                    reference="activity"
                    target="user_id"
                    sort={{ field: 'Date', order: 'DESC' }}
                >
                    <Datagrid>
                        <DateField source="Date" label="Date" showTime />
                        <TextField source="Type" label="Type" />
                        <TextField source="Result" label="Result" />
                    </Datagrid>
                </ReferenceManyField>
            </Tab>
</TabbedShowLayout>
```

Don't forget to add "activity" to your resources in

My dataprovider translate it to:

> http://localhost:3001/activity?filter=%7B%22user_id%22%3A%XXXXX%22%7D&range=%5B0%2C24%5D&sort=%5B%22Date%22%2C%22DESC%22%5D

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about that, but just was wondering if there is a way to use another page.